# Insert Picture in Datagridview ImageButton - WinForm

Tags: c#, datagridview

i use this query to create a new column in my datagridview.

```
   var q = (from c in Session.DB.PersonSet
                     where c.SchoolId == Session.loggedId && c.Date == Session.currentYear
                     select new { c.Name, c.LastName, c.PCode, c.Gender, c.Grade, c.YearOfService, edit = " " }).ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
```

how can i set a picture/icon for edit column(that set as DataGridViewButtonColumn)

i see some posts that use other ways to create Edit Button, but i want to create it in the same way that I said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommandField.EditImageUrl Property to set an image on edit button in gridview.

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server">
       <columns>
           <asp:commandfield showeditbutton="true" buttontype="Image"
                editimageurl="~\Images\EditButton.jpg"
                cancelimageurl="~\Images\CancelButton.jpg"
                updateimageurl="~\Images\UpdateButton.jpg"
                headertext="Edit Controls"/>

           <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID"
                headertext="Customer ID" />
           <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName"
                headertext="Company Name"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="Address"
                headertext="Address"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="City"
                headertext="City"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode"
                headertext="ZIP Code"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="Country"
                headertext="Country"/>
        </columns>
    </asp:gridview>
```